# If we have made 2 ads (Admob ads) code for any one app, can we also apply these ads code in any other app?

Tags: admob

If we have made 2 ads (Admob ads) code for any one app, can we also apply these ads code in any other app?
Will there be any problem?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, yes you can reuse those adUnitIds in other apps.

The longer answer is, you don't want to, as it will mean that the add network is not able to differentiate between the users of your 2+ apps, so will feed them a single stream of ads rather than targeting them more precisely to your differing user groups.

So if you don't create adUnitIds for each app then you will almost certainly reduce the revenue your ads will generate because the ads will be less focused.